# why curl extension_loaded shows false instead curl is exist

Tags: php, linux, curl

I am using a linux system and curl is installed already in my system. When I check curl version in terminal `curl --version` then output is below

```
curl 7.35.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.35.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

When I use this code in my application

```
var_dump(extension_loaded('curl'));
```

Output shows `bool(false)`

Even when I send some test data

```
$url = "my_url/?text=Test Data";

//$url = "www.google.com";

sendDataToUrl($url);
```

And my function is

```
function sendDataToUrl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

This function is not working. But same function is working in another linux server. I don't know what actual root cause and why don't working send data function?

Please help me to identify the root cause

Comment: curl and PHPs curl extension are two different things.

Comment: @tkausl, I am not clear what you said. Please explain sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to mind that `curl` or `apache default curl` and `php curl` are two different things. First you have to install your php version related curl. Like if  you use php version 5 then you have to install `php5-curl`

Open SSH

First Install CURL by typing `sudo apt-get install curl`

Then Restart Apache by typing `sudo service apache2 restart`

Then Install PHP5 CURL by typing `sudo apt-get install php5-curl`

will prompt to install… type y or yes!

Then Restart Apache by typing `sudo service apache2 restart` Done!

For details, please see this [Documentation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/curl-is-not-installed-in-your-php-installation)

Hope It will fix your problem